# Iterative time difference between two column entries in a data frame column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame that has a column of Date that is in this format as an example, 2022-07-22. The table is also below for a better understanding. I would like to get the time elapsed between each entry in hours. So far I have managed to get the elapsed time using this code:

```
startTime = data.Date.loc[1] 
endTime = data.Date.loc[2]
T= endTime-startTime
seconds = T.total_seconds()
hours = seconds / 3600
print('Difference in hours: ', hours)
```

Now I would like to do this iteratively over the entire column. Any help with this will be appreciated. Here is a small section of the table to see what I mean:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2022-07-22 15:35:13 |
| 2022-07-22 15:35:18 |
| 2022-07-22 15:35:23 |
| 2022-07-22 15:35:28 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Date' column is converted from string to datetime64[ns]. Here the difference function diff is used to calculate the 'dif ' column. Further, the differences are divided by the pd.Timedelta in one hour. I think the cycle is redundant here. And I added more hour difference in each value.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Date': ['2022-07-22 15:35:13', '2022-07-22 17:35:18', '2022-07-22 19:35:18', '2022-07-22 20:35:28']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='raise')
df['dif'] = df['Date'].diff()
df['h'] = df['dif'] / pd.Timedelta('1 hour')

print(df)
```

Output

```
                 Date             dif         h
0 2022-07-22 15:35:13             NaT       NaN
1 2022-07-22 17:35:18 0 days 02:00:05  2.001389
2 2022-07-22 19:35:18 0 days 02:00:00  2.000000
3 2022-07-22 20:35:28 0 days 01:00:10  1.002778
```

But, if you still need to iteratively, then you can do something like this:

```
a = 0
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    a = df.loc[i, 'Date'] - df.loc[i-1, 'Date']
    a = a / pd.Timedelta('1 hour')
    print(a)
```